# Unable to view Unicode on CMD or PowerShell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, putty, unicode

I do have a `Centos 7` server which i access it via `CMD` or `PowerShell`.

But it's displaying the Unicode characters as `?`

[image]

But if i accessed it via `putty` it's displayed correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by installing `Windows Terminal Preview` [Check](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/190)

Answer (score 8):

#### cmd is displaying the Unicode characters as ?

You need to set a codepage that supports the Unicode characters you are using:

- In a `cmd` shell, use `chcp`
- In `powershell`, use `$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode`

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Chcp - Change Code Page - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)
- [Understanding default encoding and Change the same in PowerShell – mohitgoyal.co](https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/03/03/understanding-default-encoding-and-change-the-same-in-powershell/)

Comment: But the system is able to view it once i logged in via `putty` with the default `chcp` of `437`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I guess `putty` is doing something already with unicode translation ...

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, putty is a GUI application, it doesn't use the Windows command window.